# C++ GUI project cannt call python tkinter GUI script successfully

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit

I code a python GUI using tkinter as follow:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

root=Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry('0x0-100+0')
info = showinfo("message", "contents")
root.destroy()
```

I can run this script successfully in PythonWin or double-click the .py file,but when I try to call the file in a VisualStudio-2013 C++ project I failed.The C++ project as follow:

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Py_Initialize();                                    
    Application::Run(gcnew Interface());
    Py_Finalize();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The Interface class is a C++ GUI class I code using VS2013(WYSIWYG,or by drag).When I click a button in the userface,the script will be called.But I cannt run it because something is wrong.
I do not know why I can run the python script directly,but I cannt call it using my VS2013 C++ project.The head scratching problem almost made me mad.
Hope your help,thanks!

Comment: how do you define "failed"? Does it crash your C++ program? Does a window appear but it's frozen? Does your computer crash? Do you get an error message? If so, what's the error?

Comment: As I have said,I just want to pop-up a infobox using python.I tried to call the python script in my c++ program,but no window appeared.You know the infobox popped up normally when I ran the script using pythonwin.

Comment: I add `sys.argv=["Main"]` to the head of the python file and it works.I can call the script using C++ project,to pop up the infobox.But I don't know why.Can you help me explain the reason?